# Problem with tint2 transparency

Tags: 10.10, gnome, compiz, openbox

I'm trying tint2 whilst using a Gnome desktop. The transparency doesn't seem to work properly, as instead of displaying the active window underneath the panel, it displays the underlying desktop background image, thus not giving a sense of real transparency ([screenshot](http://min.us/lm0GaK)). Is it possible to fix this or am I doomed unless I switch to Openbox?

Edit: using Ubuntu 10.10 with Compiz

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's using fake transparency instead of taking advantage of the compositing window manager. You should check that you have `real_transparency = 1` in your tint2 configuration.

If this doesn't help, try running tint2 from the terminal, and check the output for messages about transparency.

Comment: Checking the configuration file was the first thing I did, but the `real_transparency` line is not there. Would it be possible to insert it manually?

Comment: Yes, of course. You could even search the web for some sample configurations.